# How to create multiple rows from a single one efficiently in impala

Tags: optimization, impala

I have table1 with this format:

```
UT | temp_m1  | temp_m2  | temp_m3  | temp_m4  | air_m1  | air_m2  | air_m3  | air_m4  |
```

I would like to produce table2 with this format:

```
UT | location  |   temp  | air
```

Which would have 4 rows for each row of table1.

The easy way to achieve this would be:

```
create table2 as
Select ut,'m1' as location, temp_m1 as temp, air_m1 as air 
from table1
union all 
Select ut,'m2' as location, temp_m2 as temp, air_m2 as air 
from table1
union all 
Select ut,'m3' as location, temp_m3 as temp, air_m3 as air 
from table1
union all 
Select ut,'m4' as location, temp_m4 as temp, air_m4 as air 
from table1;
```

But looking at task manager, seems that we have to read same table 4 times and then join results.

Should be easier just to read it once and then split it at 'aim', but i can not find a way.

Comment: Did you try running it in multiple steps which might avoid over scanning of table in a single query? #1. CREATE TABLE, #2, #3, #4, #5 - INSERT statement with SELECT queries in UNION. 

Having all this in a script one after the other should do the job.

Comment: I am not getting it. For each insert i would have to make a select which would lead having to read table X times again. Could you write the example for code above please?